# Determining a value depending on where you are on a list in Excel

Tags: excel, return-value

I am tracking the progress of students reading books in class.  For the number of books they read they get a reward.  It is not 1 book = prize, 2 books = prize.  Instead there are dead spaces along the way, for example there is no reward for books 3 and 4 but there is for 5 books.  I want to be able to input the number of books each student read and have it update as to what the next reward will be.  For example:

List one

```
Name     Books     Next Tier     Prize
Sally    4         5             Candy Store
Luke     1         2             Extra coloring time
Jane     8         10            10 Extra minutes on the playground
```

And so on

The table for rewards would be

```
Books      Prize
1          Ribbon
2          Extra coloring time
5          Candy Store
7          Prize bucket
10         10 Extra minutes on the playground
```

And so on

This is just an abbreviated list and I have used if then statements previously.  However the previous list that had 18 values was cumbersome as it was, the new list has 35 values.

I have used if/then statements in the past in combination with vlookup, but with the increased number of values, it just seemed daunting.  I could still use an if statement but was hoping there would be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in C2 and copy over and down:

```
=INDEX(F$2:F$6,IFERROR(MATCH($B2,$F$2:$F$6),0)+1)
```

[image]

Comment: @EricSwart please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer, only you as the asker can do that.